# LaTeX macros in markdown

Tags: macros, markdown

I'm wondering if markdown supports even the simplest commands like

- `\newcommand`
- `\def`
- `\declaremathoperator`

Furthermore, whether or not the use of parameters is possible. For example,

- `\newcommand{\der}[2]{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please be a bit more specific as to what you intend to achieve. Is your posting mainly about markdown? If so, it may be off-topic for this site.

Comment: Yes I suppose it is. Although I assume any of the TeXsperts who are also active on this page would be familiar with such as task. The point of this question is so that I can paste already written material as answers to mathematical questions here.

Comment: This is a Markdown question; note that other sites in the StackExchange network use MathJax, but we don't, because we're mainly interested in *seeing* the code, rather than an approximate rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markdown (in its pure version) only targets HTML and does not know anything about LaTeX.
Specifically, if you meant "The markdown supported by tex.stackexchange.com" then the answer is: no, interpreting LaTeX code is not supported. 
There are many extensions though that support multiple formats as output including LaTeX.

The best tool I know that supports this is Pandoc (see the `latex_macros` extension [documented here](http://pandoc.org/README.html#latex-macros)).